# SCP command gives error "Invalid Target"

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to upload a file to my Debian server.

```
scp foo.txt amorel@cege:/home/amorel
```

The result is

```
amorel's password:

Invalid Target
lost connection
```

Any idea what it could mean ? You can find my sshd_config file here https://pastebin.com/xT0Gd1P6

Edit: a simple:

```
ssh amorel@cege ls
```

yields the same error although an interactive ssh session is working fine.

Comment: Check https://superuser.com/questions/577911/scp-lost-connection-but-ssh-works-fine

Answer (score 0):

Specify the file on the target /home/amorel/foo.txt

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfl0rx0bd59yg3t/Screenshot%202018-04-19%2010.49.38.png?dl=0)

Comment: Is the target route-able. Can you ping cege? Does /home/amoral exist on cege?

Comment: The target is route-able and I can open an interactive ssh session. I have the same error using the IP adress. This IP is only reachable using a VPN and the ping requests are timing out. And yes /home/amorel exists but the error would be "No such file or directory" or "Permission denied" if it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some output generated by shell startup scripts in non-interactive mode which causes SCP to break.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the logs from ssh. Since Debian 8 (Jessie), systemd is installed so no more /var/log/auth.log by default. To view the ssh logs:

```
journalctl -u ssh.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the ssh using -vvv as parameter:

```
ssh -vvv amorel@cege ls
```

Maybe this can help understand the issue.